# Radius of Convergence of power series, with n! and $n^n$

Tags: calculus

During revision, I came across this problem:

The set of real numbers $x$ for which the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n!x^{2n}}{n^n(1+x^{2n})}}$$ converges is __.

I tried using the ratio test, but got stuck in the process of simplification.

(The answer is the series converges for $\mathbb{R}$.)

Sincere thanks for any help.

Comment: Note the $x$ in the denominator. That isn't a power series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$
\frac{n!x^{2n}}{n^n(1+x^{2n})} \le a_n:=\frac{n!}{n^n},
$$
and
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n} \to 1/e.
$$
Therefore the series converges for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** The terms in $x$ are not a problem. For note that $\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} \lt 1$. So compare with $\sum \frac{n!}{n^n}$.  If you can show this converges you will be able to conclude that your original series converges for all $x$.